# WebXR Created interactive VR scene is not responding to controllers, it's run as video

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, webxr

I'm trying to create interactive world for my VR headset. Run this on server using web-pack and open this world using VRs browser.

I created VR world in WebXR using template found on the internet.
Next. I'm running it using web-pack on my localhost:8080.
In my PCs web browser it's working correctly, using mouse I can interact with menu which you can see on the screenshot.

But when I enter VR mode (using button in the right-bottom) in my VRs browser, I can't interact with the world (when I tried different web browsers sometimes I got only blackscreen).
It is run with this mode, where I have 2 flat screens instead VR world.

Also, in VR there is a small menu in the middle with "play" button. and go forward 10 seconds button.

[image]

Am I entering some kind of "watch video" mode instead interactive mode?
How can I enable interactions for my VR headset?

Am I newbie in WebXR world and I couldn't find anything about this on forums. Is my approach to this issue is wrong?

This is code which I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Babylon.js sample code</title>

        <!-- Babylon.js -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://assets.babylonjs.com/generated/Assets.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/ammo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/cannon.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/Oimo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/earcut.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/materialsLibrary/babylonjs.materials.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/proceduralTexturesLibrary/babylonjs.proceduralTextures.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/postProcessesLibrary/babylonjs.postProcess.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/loaders/babylonjs.loaders.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/serializers/babylonjs.serializers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/gui/babylon.gui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/inspector/babylon.inspector.bundle.js"></script>

        <style>
            html, body {
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #renderCanvas {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                touch-action: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");

        var startRenderLoop = function (engine, canvas) {
            engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
                if (sceneToRender && sceneToRender.activeCamera) {
                    sceneToRender.render();
                }
            });
        }

        var engine = null;
        var scene = null;
        var sceneToRender = null;
        var createDefaultEngine = function() { return new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true, { preserveDrawingBuffer: true, stencil: true,  disableWebGL2Support: false}); };
        var textblock;
        
        var createScene = function () {
            var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
        
            var camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera("Camera", new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,-20),scene);
            camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
            var sunLight = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("sunLight", new BABYLON.Vector3(0,1,0), scene);
        
            // Plane Mesh used for GUI elements
            var planeForMainMenu = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("planeForMainMenu", 20);
            planeForMainMenu.position.y = 5;
        
            var planeForColorPicker = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("planeForColorPicker", 20);
            planeForColorPicker.position.y = 5;
            planeForColorPicker.position.x = 20;
        
            // GUI
            var textureForMainMenu = BABYLON.GUI.AdvancedDynamicTexture.CreateForMesh(planeForMainMenu);
            var textureForColorPicker = BABYLON.GUI.AdvancedDynamicTexture.CreateForMesh(planeForColorPicker);
        
            var stackPanel = new BABYLON.GUI.StackPanel();  
            stackPanel.top = "100px";
            textureForMainMenu.addControl(stackPanel);    
        
            var clickMeButton = BABYLON.GUI.Button.CreateSimpleButton("clickMeButton", "Click Me");
            clickMeButton.width = 1;
            clickMeButton.height = "100px";
            clickMeButton.color = "white";
            clickMeButton.fontSize = 50;
            clickMeButton.background = "green";
            clickMeButton.onPointerUpObservable.add(function() {
                if (VRHelper) {
                    VRHelper.displayLaserPointer = !VRHelper.displayLaserPointer;
                }
            });
            stackPanel.addControl(clickMeButton);
        
            textblock = new BABYLON.GUI.TextBlock();
            textblock.height = "150px";
            textblock.fontSize = 100;
            textblock.text = "please pick an option:";
            stackPanel.addControl(textblock);   
        
            addRadio("option 1", stackPanel);
            addRadio("option 2", stackPanel);
            addRadio("option 3", stackPanel);
            addRadio("option 4", stackPanel);
            addRadio("option 5", stackPanel);    
        
            var picker = new BABYLON.GUI.ColorPicker();
            picker.horizontalAlignment = BABYLON.GUI.Control.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT_LEFT;
            picker.height = "450px";
            picker.width = "450px";
            picker.onValueChangedObservable.add(function(value) { // value is a color3
                sphereMat.diffuseColor = value;
            });    
            textureForColorPicker.addControl(picker);  
        
            // Sphere material color will be updated by the value of the Color Picker
            var sphere = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateSphere("sphere", 12, 2, scene);
            sphere.position.x = 10;
            var sphereMat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("sphereMat", scene);
            sphere.material = sphereMat;
        
            var VRHelper = scene.createDefaultVRExperience();
            VRHelper.enableInteractions();
        
            return scene;
        };
        
        var addRadio = function(text, parent) {
            var button = new BABYLON.GUI.RadioButton();
            button.width = "40px";
            button.height = "40px";
            button.color = "white";
            button.background = "green";     
            button.onIsCheckedChangedObservable.add(function(state) {
                if (state) {
                    textblock.text = "You selected " + text;
                }
            }); 
            var header = BABYLON.GUI.Control.AddHeader(button, text, "400px", { isHorizontal: true, controlFirst: true });
            header.height = "100px";
            header.children[1].fontSize = 80;
            header.children[1].onPointerUpObservable.add(function() {
                button.isChecked = !button.isChecked;
            });
            parent.addControl(header);    
        }
                window.initFunction = async function() {
                    
                    
                    var asyncEngineCreation = async function() {
                        try {
                        return createDefaultEngine();
                        } catch(e) {
                        console.log("the available createEngine function failed. Creating the default engine instead");
                        return createDefaultEngine();
                        }
                    }

                    window.engine = await asyncEngineCreation();
        if (!engine) throw 'engine should not be null.';
        startRenderLoop(engine, canvas);
        window.scene = createScene();};
        initFunction().then(() => {sceneToRender = scene                    
        });

        // Resize
        window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
            engine.resize();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```